# How do I save a rtf file from a WPF RichTextBox in Powershell?

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, richtextbox

I need to save the file from a `RichTextBox` WPF that's been created in PowerShell

I've tried piping through `System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter`, and I've been banging my head on tons of stuff I deleted back out of. I just can't seem to get this one.

```
if ($saveFile) {
   $tr = new-object System.Windows.Documents.TextRange($RichEdit.Document.ContentStart,                                                 
                                   $RichEdit.Document.ContentEnd)
   $ascii = (new-Object System.Text.ASCIIEncoding).getbytes($tr)

   #  $docStream = new-Object System.IO.MemoryStream($ascii,$false)
   $docStream = New-Object IO.FileStream $saveFile ,'Append','Write','Read'
   $out = new-object System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save $tr, $docStream
}
```

Comment: ````        <RichTextBox x:Name="RichEdit" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run Text=""/>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>````

Comment: Figured out how to get just the text, still need to be able to save rtf :)

````$tr = new-object System.Windows.Documents.TextRange ($RichEdit.Document.ContentStart, $RichEdit.Document.ContentEnd)

$tr.text ````

Answer (score 0):

The `SaveFile` Method can be used to do this.

```
$RichTextBox.SaveFile('C:\Path\File.rtf')
```

It will store Font and Colors automatically. If plain text output is needed it can be done as follows:

```
$RichTextBox.SaveFile('C:\Path\File.rtf', 'PlainText')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($saveFile) {
  $RichEdit.SelectAll()
  $as = New-Object IO.FileStream $saveFile ,'Create'
  $a = $RichEdit.Selection.Save($as,[Windows.DataFormats]::Rtf)
}
```

Comment: I doubt that this works at all, not to mention solves the problem. In order to convince me otherwise, please explain how you mean this to work and solve the problem.

Comment: @Yunnosch is correct, it will not work. There is no Method called `Save` but there is `SaveFile`. Look at my answer for an example.